# Rotation question. Trigonometry equation.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How do I solve for the angle "t" in the following equation:

$$\cos(t)  ( p_x \cos(s) + p_y \sin(s) ) + \sin(t) ( p_y \cos(s) - p_x \sin(s) ) = t_x \cos(s) + t_y \sin(s)$$

where $p_{x/y}$, $t_{x/y}$, and s are known.

I've tried to substitute cos by sqrt(1-sin^2), or tried to make the equation become cos^2 + sin^2 = 1, but got stuck.

To provide the physical meaning of this equation ( see picture link below) , basically this is to find out the angle such that after the rotation around the cyan coordinate, the blue axis can point directly toward the pink point.

[physical problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM4Lb.png)

[end goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAiOT.png)

---

Edit:
Besides the solution Yves gave, Jean also gave a [geometrical interpretation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbKH6.png) and the solution below.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I am finding this difficult to follow. It looks as though the coordinates $(t_x,t_y)$ are irrelevant, because you know the angle $s$. So you just need the angle $u$ between the vertical axis and the line through the origin and the point $(p_x,p_y)$. Then $t=s+u$. Is that correct?

Comment: @almagest, sorry my first picture was incorrectly drawn. I just corrected it. s should be the angle indicated in the new picture. Yves provided the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the $p_{x/y}$ using polar coordinates (caution, $\pi$ is the polar argument, not the Archimedes constant).

$$\cos(t) (p \cos(\pi)\cos(s) + p\sin(\pi)\sin(s) ) + \sin(t)( p\sin(\pi)\cos(s) - p\cos(\pi)\sin(s) )\\= t_x \cos(s) + t_y \sin(s).$$

Then

$$\cos(t) p \cos(\pi-s) + \sin(t) p\sin(\pi-s) =t_x \cos(s) + t_y \sin(s),$$

$$\cos(t-\pi+s) = \frac{t_x \cos(s) + t_y \sin(s)}p$$

and

$$t=\pi-s\pm\arccos\left(\frac{t_x \cos(s) + t_y \sin(s)}p\right).$$

Comment: ah, smart! polar coordinate is the trick! thanks a lot

Comment: @AlexTPF: in fact the trigonometric equation $a\cos t+b\sin t=c$ has a well-known solution. But in this case, the coefficients have a particular expression.

Comment: yeah, I then found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAokL9gKy98 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5LEOplnBxg which are probably what you referred to the well-known solution?

Comment: @AlexTPF: that's it. Though I prefer to solve in a different way: $a\cos t+b\sin t=c\leftrightarrow a^2\cos^2t=a^2(1-\sin^2t)=(c-b\sin t)^2$, which is quadratic in $\sin t$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a more geometrical solution.

Let us write your equation under the following matrix form :

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)&\sin(t)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p_x&p_y\\p_y&-p_x\end{pmatrix}}_{V_1^T}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\cos(s)\\\sin(s)\end{pmatrix}}_V
=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}t_x&t_y\end{pmatrix}}_{V_2^T}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\cos(s)\\\sin(s)\end{pmatrix}}_V$$

meaning that $V_1$ and $V_2$ have the same dot product with $V$.

Therefore,

$$V_1=V_2+kW\ \ \text{where} \ \ W:=\binom{\ \ \sin(s)}{-\cos(s)}\tag{1} $$

is a vector n orthogonal to $V$ and $k$ any real number.

(with words : $V_1$ and $V_2$ differ by a multiple of vector $W$).

As, by transposition, $V_1=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}p_x&p_y\\p_y&-p_x\end{pmatrix}}_M\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)\\\sin(t)\end{pmatrix}$, relationship (1) becomes :

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)\\\sin(t)\end{pmatrix}=M^{-1}(V_2+kW)=a M(V_2+kW) \ \ \text{where} \ \ a:=\frac{1}{p_x^2+p_y^2}\tag{2}$$

Therefore, (2) can be explicited in the following way:

$$\begin{cases}\cos(t)&=&a(t_x+k\sin(s))p_x+a(t_y-k \cos(s))p_y\\ \sin(t)&=&a(t_x+k\sin(s))p_y-a(t_y-k \cos(s))p_x\end{cases}\tag{3}$$

In fact, parameter $k$ can be found out of these equations by writing... $\cos(t)^2+\sin(t)^2=1$.

Using (3), one gets at once the value of $t$.

The interest of this solution (sophisticated, I admit...) is to give a method of attack of such problems that can be usable in other circumstances.

Comment: Coming up with the matrix form and the geometrical interpretation, V1 = V2 + kw is pretty amazing! thanks!